# TCP client - server code. Doesn't do anything

Tags: python, tcp

Tried to paste the code from one book (TCP/IP learning) to send a message from client to server. But nothing happens, except the message "The server is ready to receive".

Server code:

```
from socket import *

serverPort = 12000
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)

print('The server is ready to receive')

while 1:
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
    capitalizedSentence = sentence.upper()
    connectionSocket.send(capitalizedSentence)
    connectionSocket.close()
```

Client code:

```
from socket import *

serverName = '0.0.0.0.0'
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort))
sentence = input('Input lowercase sentence: ')
clientSocket.send(sentence)
modifiedSentence = clientSocket.recv(1024)

print('From Server: ', modifiedSentence)
clientSocket.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You entered the wrong server name. The server name is actually the IP address, and `0.0.0.0.0` is not a valid IP address.
 
Try changing

```
serverName = '0.0.0.0.0' -> '0.0.0.0' or '127.0.0.1'
```

Comment: The IP adress was changed in purpose and its like an example. However does two devices have to be connected to one IP adress?

Comment: @Illu Minat your server is having address (ip) if client wish to connect server then client will find server ip.  If you are running Client and server on same device then ip will be same. But in real life server is in web so have different ip and client find that server by matching ip. You can have server and client on different device(different ip) but until it is hosted on web you have to keep both device on same network (same wifi) else your client code will not find it.

Answer (score 0):

The value for *serverName* is not a valid IP address ('0.0.0.0.0'). Try `0.0.0.0` instead.

If you want to check for a valid IP address beforehand, try this.

```
if re.match(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', input_string):
    serverName = input_string  # True, valid
else:
    print('Invalid IP Address')
```